# How to update multiple mongodb documents using spring mongodb template with findAndModify method?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

How to update multiple mongodb documents using spring mongodb template with findAndModify method? Currently its updating only a single document but there are more than 1 documents which satisfy the query criteria